# Can there exist a world where every consistent effective FOL theory can be written and satisfied in some part of it?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, alternative-set-theories

is it consistent to postulate the existence of a set $W$ and a membership relation $\in$ and the following axioms about it:

1. **Transitivity:** $\forall x \in W: x \subset W$
2. **Extensionality:** $\forall x,y \in W: \forall z (z \in x \iff z \in y) \to x=y $
3. **Comprehension:** $\exists x \forall y (y \in x \iff y \in W \land \phi)$
4. **Pairing:** $\forall a,b \in W: \{a,b\} \in W$
5. **Syntax:** Any consistent recursively axiomatized first order theory that doesn't contain $W, \in$ among its symbols, can be written in $W$
6. **Semantics:** For every consistent recursively axiomatized first order theory $T$ that doesn't contain $W,\in$ among its symbols; there is a subset $M$ of $W$ such that $M \models T$.

In nustshall $W$ is a world in which every consistent effectively generated first order theory can be written and satisfied in a sector of it.

Is this consistent?

Comment: What does "can be written in $W$ mean?" For a first-order theory $T$ and a subset $M$ of $W$, what does $M\models T$ mean? (Does this implicitly include the condition that $M$ is a structure in the language of $T$?)

Comment: @AlexKruckman $W$ have all naturals in it, and actually it easily interpret second order arithmetic over sets of its naturals.  Now we can use finite tuples of the naturals in $W$ to write up any logical theory in a way similar to Godel's numbering. Since every effectively generated theory is countable, then this can be done in $W$. to be continued..

Comment: @AlexKruckman, about the satisfaction, here its mean that $W$ would prove that in a sector ot it. Every element of the signature of any theory can be represented with an object in $W$, so for example any $n$-$ary$ predicate symbol of $T$, would be represented by a set of $n$-sized tuples in $W$, and so on.., so everything is done in the language of FOL(=,$\in$). The definition of $M \models T$ is the conventional one, done in FOL(=, $\in$)

Comment: Doesn't $V_{omega+k}$ for some small $k$ satisfy your "axioms"?

Comment: @AlexKruckman, I'm not sure of this. For example suppose that "ZF+Reinhardt cardinal exists" is consistent, would that necessarily mean that $V_{\omega+k}$ would always have some subset of it that serve as a model for that theory? And would that apply for every consistent effectively generated theory? I personally don't know the answer, and that this can be the case, hence my question.

Comment: By Löwenheim-Skolem, every countable  theory with infinite models has a model with domain $\omega$.